# SQL, Postgresql: optimal way to query multiple cells from one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a better way to write this set of queries so the table only gets scanned once?

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE id = 1;
SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE id = 2;
SELECT column3 FROM table WHERE id = 3;
```

This alternative is a bit wasteful as it fetches 9 cells, when I only need 3:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Is there a more efficient way to pull exactly the 3 cells I need with 1 scan of the table?

Comment: Is this an actual query? It seems nonsensical to me ...

Comment: How do you know it's wasteful if you haven't measured it?

Answer (score 1):

Scan the table once with

```
with t as (
  select * from tablename where id in (1, 2, 3)
)
```

and then with with separate `select` statements or with `union`, scan only the 3 fetched rows:

```
select column1 col from t where id = 1
union all
select column2 col from t where id = 2
union all
select column3 col from t where id = 3
```

See the [demo](https://rextester.com/BPDS59502)

Or in 1 row:

```
select 
  (select column1 from t where id = 1) column1,
  (select column2 from t where id = 2) column2,
  (select column3 from t where id = 3) column3;
```

See the [demo](https://rextester.com/PBEZJ56137)

Comment: My first thought is the WITH block creates overhead of an extra query. Does the WITH block add overall performance benefit to the 3 SELECT statements? Or would the 3 SELECT statements be equally efficient without the WITH block?

Comment: The benefit of WITH is that it scans the table only **once** and it fetches (in this case) 3 rows. Then there are 3 insignificant select statements on these 3 rows only.

Answer (score 0):

The table isn't "scanned". As you are looking for three rows of which you already know the IDs, the IDs will be quickly got from the primary key index (with binary search). So the table addresses are got from the index and the rows get read from the table addresses directly. (That would be different, if you looked up a column that isn't indexed.)

However, there are two reasons to combine the three queries:

1. Every time you send a query to the DBMS, it must be interpreted and an access plan built. So it's better to send one query instead of three.
2. Let's say the rows for IDs 1 and 3 are on disk block x, and the row for ID 2 on disk block y. If you ask for all three rows at once, the DBMS may optimize disk access by asking for #1, #3, #2 instead of #1 , #2, #3.

The combined query is:

```
SELECT column1 AS col FROM table WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT column2 AS col FROM table WHERE id = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT column3 AS col FROM table WHERE id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

First these three queries will not necessarily scan the table three times.  If you have an index on `id`, then this is just index lookups.

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE id = 1;
SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE id = 2;
SELECT column3 FROM table WHERE id = 3;
```

If you really like, you can rephrase the query as:

```
select (case when id = 1 then column1
             when id = 2 then column2
             when id = 3 then column3
        end)
from t
where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

This assumes that the three columns have compatible types.